# Get x y coordinates while the finger is on the custom View

Tags: android, events, view, touch, android-nestedscrollview

I created custom View.

I need to get the X and Y coordinates when my finger is on this View.

To do this, I use the **onTouchEvent** method, but for some reason it is triggered once and I do not understand why.

***What could be the problem?***

---

**MyCustomView:**

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

private int layoutWidth, layoutHeight = 0;
private radius = 0;
private isInit = false;


public MyCustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}


private void initMyCustomView() {
    layoutWidth = getWidth();
    layoutHeight = getHeight();
    radius = Math.min(height, width) / 2;
    isInit = true;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!isInit) initMyCustomView();

    drawCircle(canvas);

    postInvalidateDelayed(500);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("LOGD", "onTouchEvent");

    return true;
}

private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(layoutWidth / 2, layoutHeight / 2, radius, paint);
}
}
```

**SOLVE:**

The problem was that **onTouchEvent** worked, but if you moved your finger above or below the point of pressing, it stopped working.

It turned out that this happens if your *CustomView* (or any other *View*, *Layout*, etc.) is placed in a *NestedScrollView*.

This is easy to fix, you just need to add the line *getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);* in **onTouchEvent**:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Do not call invalidate(); from onDraw Method

Comment: Also, To get points **event.x** and **event.y** inside onTouchEvent will work.

Comment: @DhavalPatel, I commented out " invalidate();", but the problem remained(

Comment: Comment postInvalidateDelayed also. Both will call the onDraw method again.

Comment: commented out too

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate();` and `postInvalidateDelayed(500);` will repeatedly be called onDraw method and your code will forever be stuck in an infinite loop.

Here, is optimized version of your code. give it a try.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class MyCustomView extends View {

    private int layoutWidth, layoutHeight = 0;
    private int radius = 0;
    private boolean isInit = false;
    private Paint paint;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // avoid object creation on onDraw method
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        //Handle view size change
        initMyCustomView();
    }

    private void initMyCustomView() {
        layoutWidth = getWidth();
        layoutHeight = getHeight();
        radius = Math.min(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) / 2;
        isInit = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (!isInit) initMyCustomView();

        drawCircle(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("LOGD", "onTouchEvent:"+event.getX()+","+event.getY());
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        return true;
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(layoutWidth / 2, layoutHeight / 2, radius, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've noticed that onTouchEvent works well until Y changes significantly. There is no such problem with changing X. Very strange.

Comment: Here's what I get in LogCat:


onTouchEvent:
**261.0,132.0**
onTouchEvent:
**261.0,132.0**
onTouchEvent:
**261.0,132.0**
onTouchEvent:
**261.0,132.0**
onTouchEvent:
**266.20764,145.21716**
onTouchEvent:
**273.62823,161.58212**
onTouchEvent:
**281.31348,175.76422**
onTouchEvent:
**527.5726,248.14511**

Comment: Note that the values change dramatically at the end and then
**onTouchEvent**
stops working.

Comment: why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry buddy, no idea on this one.